# iOS7 Video Player not showing captions

Tags: ios, html, web-applications, video, subtitle

I designed a sample web application in which i used the video tag like this:

```
<video src="test.mp4" width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
 <track kind="subtitles" src="test.srt" srclang="en" type="text/vtt">
</video>
```

When i tested this out on iPhone5 with iOS7, on selecting English from Closed captioning menu in the video player, no subtitles showed up. Am i doing it the wrong way?

What is the correct way of showing subtitles on the video? I couldn't find anything from iOS Developer Library. So, thought of putting this up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you've created that code correctly (not a dev) however we're currently having trouble with captions created using WebVTT format. Captions are there, they work on desktop no problem but on iOS7 they only show once you've turned captions off then back on.

When you load the video, and toggle the captions button on the player the captions are defaulted to On but do not display. If you toggle captions to Off, close captions options, re-open captions option and toggle On, they display.